PGSQL - How to optimize execution time for query stored into a varchar column
I'm currently working for a client that need product theoric price redirection getting the minimum sub-value whenever the initial-value is null
My question is how can I speed up reloading time with the current solution or replace it with a more efficient one ?
For a little bit of context, I'm working with Talend and PostgreSQL. Talend is the request scheduler for Pgsql and cannot manage this problem.
For example :
enter image description here
There is 19 specifics rules that applies for each theoric price but there is 3 really distinctive patterns :

COALESCE(sub-value-1, sub-value-2, 'N/A')

LEAST(sub-value-1, sub-value-2)

COASLESCE( LEAST(sub-value-1, sub-value-2), LEAST(sub-value-3, sub-value-4), 'N/A')


for each specific product - theoric price it choose one of the three patterns and a number of sub-values (there is 19 sub-value)
The method I tried is to create the following temp table :
enter image description here
and the following procedure :
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "DATA_HUB".insert_tarifs(
    tarifs varchar
)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
    DECLARE
    rows_tarif record;
BEGIN
    FOR rows_tarif IN
        SELECT * FROM GET_PRODUIT_TARIF_REGLE_CALCUL_CAST_TO_DOUBLE WHERE factory_tarifs_pim_code_tarif LIKE '%' || tarifs || '%'
    LOOP
                --For each row, prepare stored query in the row
        EXECUTE format(rows_tarif.requete_regle_calcul, rows_tarif.produit_code_ean, rows_tarif.produit_code_ean);
    END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$;
ALTER PROCEDURE "DATA_HUB".insert_tarifs()
    OWNER TO XXXXXXX;

Example of requete_regle_calcul in the set of 19 requests to calculate product theoric price:
SET extra_float_digits = 2;
INSERT INTO LISTE_PRODUIT_TARIF_SOURCE_DESTINATION
SELECT
    %L as ean_produit,
    'ts2_pan_n2' as tarif_source_code,
    ts2_pan_n2 as tarif_source_valeur,
    LEAST(ts1_pan_n2,ts3_pan_n2,ts4_pan_n2,ts5_pan_n2,ts6_pan_n2,pan_ent_n2,pan_mag_n2,pab_mag_n2) as tarif_cible_valeur, 
    CASE  LEAST(ts1_pan_n2,ts3_pan_n2,ts4_pan_n2,ts5_pan_n2,ts6_pan_n2,pan_ent_n2,pan_mag_n2,pab_mag_n2)
                WHEN ts1_pan_n2 THEN 'ts1_pan_n2'
                WHEN ts3_pan_n2 THEN 'ts3_pan_n2'
                WHEN ts4_pan_n2 THEN 'ts4_pan_n2'
                WHEN ts5_pan_n2 THEN 'ts5_pan_n2'
                WHEN ts6_pan_n2 THEN 'ts6_pan_n2'
                WHEN pan_ent_n2 THEN 'pan_ent_n2'
                WHEN pan_mag_n2 THEN 'pan_mag_n2'
                WHEN pab_mag_n2 THEN 'pab_mag_n2'
    END AS tarif_cible_code   
FROM
    GET_PRODUIT_TARIF_REGLE_CALCUL_CAST_TO_DOUBLE
WHERE
    produit_code_ean = %L;

The point of this request is to calculate the redirection and which column where used.
However I encounter performances issues. On a set of 100 rows it take 17 secondes to calculate theoric prices. For the whole set it would take more than 15 hours. In reality even after 24 hours, the dataset didn't manage to load.

Start timing your queries, pick the slow ones, and use explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) to see what takes so long. If you need help, post all the DDL for the tables and indexes involved and the query plan itself. All in plain text, never as an image.
